# How do I create a labeling column for strings based on another DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frames

```
import pandas as pd
df_occurencies = pd.DataFrame({'day':[1,2,3,4,5],
                           'occ':[['frog','wasp','bee'],
                           ['frog','whale','barley','orchid'],
                           ['orchid','barley','frog'],
                           ['orchid','whale','frog'],
                           ['orchid','barley','tulip']]})

df_kingdoms = pd.DataFrame({'item':['frog','wasp','bee',
                              'whale','barley','orchid',
                              'tulip'],
                      'kingdom':['animalia','animalia','animalia',
                              'animalia','plantae','plantae',
                              'plantae']})
```

I need to set up another column, classifying the observations in column `occ` based on the values of the `df_kingdoms` values.
The values are all heterogeneous, so the desired outcome would be like this:

```
    day                     occ        desired_result
0    1              [frog, wasp, bee]   "animals"
1    2  [frog, whale, barley, orchid]   "animals and plants"
2    3         [orchid, barley, frog]   "mostly plants"
3    4          [orchid, whale, frog]   "mostly animals"
4    5        [orchid, barley, tulip]   "plants"
```

I know that there are many ways to solve this, I've tried unsuccessfully a defined function with lots of `.loc`s that I think is not even worth posting. And I need to perform this on large datasets, so faster is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
dic_kd={i:j for i,j in zip(df_kingdoms.item,df_kingdoms.kingdom)}
desired_output=[]
for I in df_occurencies.occ:
    list_aux=[dic_kd[i] for i in I]
    if (list_aux.count('animalia')!=0) and (list_aux.count('plantae')==0) :
        desired_output.append('animals')
    elif (list_aux.count('animalia')==0) and (list_aux.count('plantae')!=0) :
        desired_output.append('plants')
    elif list_aux.count('animalia')>list_aux.count('plantae'):
        desired_output.append('mostly animals')
    elif list_aux.count('animalia')<list_aux.count('plantae'):
        desired_output.append('mostly plants')
    else:
        desired_output.append('animals and plants')

df_occurencies['desired output']=desired_output
```

Tell me if you don't understand anything and I'll help you